# Which version of Eclipse should I run on OSX? 32bit or 64bit?

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-3.6

This may be a silly question but should I use the 32 bit or 64 bit version of Eclipse on my Mac?

I'm fully up to date with Snow Leopard and all patches and I have a pretty recent iMac (30", Dual Core, 3GB)

I thought that Java on Snow Leopard was now 64 bit only so can't understand why there is a 32bit download. Is it just the Eclipse download page that is showing 32 bit for older versions of OSX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably better off with the 64-bit edition.  Nearly all the system software is 64-bit in Snow Leopard, and if you only run 64-bit apps, you don't pay the cost of having to load the 32-bit runtimes (which can consume quite a lot of memory).  It may also benefit from the 64-bit memory model, though I'm not sure how well the JVM takes advantage of that yet.  I expect the 32-bit version is provided for Leopard (and earlier) compatability.

Comment: It is possible to use Java6 in 32 bit mode in Snow Leopard. Just use the -d32 switch to start it. It is seldom needed, but sometimes useful, as 32 applications use a bit less memory.

Comment: Does eclipse in 32bit mode use less memory than in 64bit mode?  Given that Java has fixed memory limits, I don't see huge benefits to having it run in 64 bit mode.

Comment: I don't know off hand; it depends on several factors. The JRE itself may technically use less memory in 32-bit mode (simply due to the word size and alignment) but as mentioned above, if it is the only process requiring the 32-bit runtimes (CoreFoundation, Cocoa, etc, etc) then overall it could actually be consuming more memory than the 64-bit edition (which will use the runtimes already loaded by the system).

Comment: 64bit JVMs often use compressed references, in which case references still take 4 bytes.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905594/whats-the-purpose-of-compressed-object-pointers

Answer (score 1):

I would use 64bit Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

safe bit is 32-bit :)